# Laravel error Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So I am working on this application and I am working with rolemanagement and what not. Now everything worked fine until suddenly I was told that I was apparenty trying to put a string where it should be an array. I undid anything from the page in question to make sure, but the error is still given.

It is really damn frustrating because everything worked fine and now it is broken to bits. I have no clue what's going on. All I know is that I'm trying to pass a wrong datatype somewhere. Please help if you know more about this.

Admin Controller:
[image]

My edit.blade.php
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I foolishly forgot to put brackets around an array that I was defining for a gate in the AuthServiceProvider. I'm just glad I found it out now.